# What's the source of this NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

OK, so I'm writing an Android app, and am trying to download a Bitmap and set it as an ImageView. The code is below for the relevant parts:

```
    private class GetContactInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ContactInfo[]> {

    @Override
    protected ContactInfo[] doInBackground(String... url) {
        // Instantiate what is needed
        URL json = null;

        //Set the JSON URL
        try {
            json = new URL(url[0]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Use Jackson library to read out the data from the contacts page
        try {
            contacts = mapper.readValue(json, ContactInfo[].class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Add everything into the bitmap ArrayList
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            String imageURL = contacts[i].getSmallImageURL();

            // Download the Bitmap and add it to the ArrayList
            try {
                bitmap.add(downloadBitmap(imageURL));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Return statement
        return contacts;
    }
```

---

```
public Bitmap downloadBitmap(String imageURL) throws IOException {

    URL url = new URL(imageURL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
    if (bitmap == null) {
        Log.e("Null", "Bitmap null");
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

The log never catches that bitmap is null, or at least it doesn't show it (I see in the stack trace that there are 4 more errors, but they never show up and I'm not sure how to expand it to show the other errors.)

The NullPointerException comes at the `bitmap.add(downloadBitmap(imageURL));` line. So somehow my `downloadBitmap` function is returning a null result. Any ideas?

Edit: I'm not sure if this matters, but the images in the URLs are .jpeg files.

Edit 2: Put this in the comments so I will edit it into my post as well, bitmap is declared as a Global Variable like so `ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap;` This is so I can later use it in my onPostExecute method.

Comment: It wouldn't matter if `downloadBitmap` returned `null`, since you can add `null` to an `ArrayList` with no problem. More likely, `bitmap` is `null` in the first snippet. Please show where `bitmap` is declared and initialized.

Comment: Pasting the stacktrace itself might be useful as well

Comment: Also consider using more unique and descriptive names for variables. `bitmap` doesn't sound like a list to me, and it's confusing to look at (and discuss) your snippet because you have `Bitmap bitmap` in another context later.

Comment: Edited to include my entire AsyncTask doInBackground method. Basically I grab a lit of the ContactInfo using Jackson JSON parser, then using that, extract the smallImageURL to go and download the image into a Bitmap. EDIT: Ahh, shoot, I think I initiated as a Global Variable in order to use it later in onPostExecute, initialized like so: `ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap;`

Comment: @BillL This still doesn't show where you are declaring and initializing `bitmap` (the list).

Comment: @Bill If the error is at line bitmap.add(downloadBitmap(imageURL)); then your bitmap is null and not downloadBitmap(imageURL).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said the error is at line

```
bitmap.add(downloadBitmap(imageURL));
```

which means culprit is your **bitmap** variable and not downloadBitmap(imageURL) method.

Also, in your edit you have mentioned that you have declared bitmap as a global variable - ArrayList bitmap;

In order to access(add bitmap onjects to it) this globally declared variable you must initialize it.

In your onCreate do -

```
bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

and the NPE must go.

Comment: That worked, but now I have another NullPointer Error in my ListAdapter line:

`adapter = new ListAdapter(local, bitmap, contacts);`

Adapter was declared as a global variable as well, but is instantiated here, I know from before previous edits that both local and contacts are not null, so again a problem exists with bitmap.

Comment: See, I knew that. Happened many a times with me as well. :) Now for this one could you please post the ListAdapter you have and the log cat as well?

Answer (score 0):

While you are downloading images from the Internet, you should use an async request. In `downloadBitmap` the connection is downloading in another thread, but the main thread has returned `bitmap` immediately, whether or not the downloading is accomplished.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Just start another AsyncTask? I want to be able to keep my ContactInfo array list and my BitMap array list together in order to then use them to populate my ListView, which is why I'm trying to do it all inside of one AsyncTask.

Comment: In my opinion, you should only put the download job in a async block. Generating a list itself is not a time-consuming task, but Internet requests are.

Comment: Right but I need to download the JSON data as well as download the images from the URL that I get from the JSON data (which is located on the internet as well)

Comment: `Handler` class will give you a hand. Sorry but I don't know how to paste an example of codes here, as it keeps returning an error of overlength message.

Comment: It does take two async jobs, one is to get the JSON data after which you should show the `ContactInfo` on your view. The other is to downloading the images, at the same time you can use a placeholder on the view (maybe a default avatar). When the downloading jobs are done, replace the placeholder image with the one you just got from Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you initialized `bitmap`? As far as I can tell, it is null and you are using that null object, so Null Pointer Exception come out. That's from the information you provided. If the error is occurred inside the function, it's the different matter.